# SQL Server XML - embedding a dataset within an existing node

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

There are numerous examples of inserting record sets into XML, but they tend to be very basic and do not cover my specific requirement. In the following instance, I want to extract some data to XML and within that, I need a collection of nodes to represent a variable number of records. I know it can be done, as I have an example, but I do not understand how it works. I do understand my code to return the dataset might make no sense, but it is only meant to represent an example of what I am try to achieve.

```
SELECT 'Node' AS [A/B],
(
    SELECT x.Item
    FROM (
        SELECT 'Line1' AS [Item]
        FROM (SELECT 1 AS x) x

        UNION

        SELECT 'Line2' AS [Item]
        FROM (SELECT 1 AS x) x
    ) x
    FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('Lines'), TYPE
)
FROM (SELECT 1 AS x) x
FOR XML PATH('Demo')
```

This gives me the following:

```
<Demo>
    <A>
        <B>Node</B>
    </A>
    <Lines>
        <Item>Line1</Item>
        <Item>Line2</Item>
    </Lines>
</Demo>
```

What I want is the following:

```
<Demo>
    <A>
        <B>Node</B>
        <Lines>
            <Item>Line1</Item>
            <Item>Line2</Item>
        </Lines>
    </A>
</Demo>
```

Can anyone help or point me to the correct answer please?

Comment: If you could add some example data to go with your desired output, ideally as a `create table` statement, you will likely get more help here, as we would have something to easily copy and paste into our own environments to test our ideas

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1):

Making some assumptions on the structure of your source data that you should be able to easily adjust around, the following script gives you the output you are after, even across multiple `Node` groups:

## Query

```
declare @t table([Node] varchar(10),Line varchar(10));
insert into @t values
 ('Node1','Line1')
,('Node1','Line2')
,('Node1','Line3')
,('Node1','Line4')
,('Node2','Line1')
,('Node2','Line2')
,('Node2','Line3')
,('Node2','Line4')
;

with n as
(
    select distinct [Node]
    from @t
)
select n.[Node] as [B]
      ,(select t.Line as Item
        from @t as t
        where t.[Node] = n.[Node]
        for xml path(''), root('Lines'), type
       )
from n
for xml path('A'), root('Demo')
;
```

---

## Output

```
<Demo>
  <A>
    <B>Node1</B>
    <Lines>
      <Item>Line1</Item>
      <Item>Line2</Item>
      <Item>Line3</Item>
      <Item>Line4</Item>
    </Lines>
  </A>
  <A>
    <B>Node2</B>
    <Lines>
      <Item>Line1</Item>
      <Item>Line2</Item>
      <Item>Line3</Item>
      <Item>Line4</Item>
    </Lines>
  </A>
</Demo>
```

Comment: That has pointed my in the right direction. I am working on XML with an extra group inside A, for which I need an additional query with its own root. I did not think of that.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to place `A` as the node name of the outer query, and `Demo` as its root.**

```sql
SELECT 'Node' AS [B],
(
    SELECT x.Item
    FROM (
        SELECT 'Line1' AS [Item]

        UNION

        SELECT 'Line2' AS [Item]
    ) x
    FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('Lines'), TYPE
)
FOR XML PATH('A'), ROOT('Demo'), TYPE
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/132798)

Comment: Your output tag ordering does not match the requirement in the OP

Comment: Oops fixed now.

Comment: @Charlieface, It is good to see a working example. It has not immediately fixed my issue, but it has pointed me in the right direction. The xml that I am working on has an extra group inside [Lines] and I can now see I need an extra query with its own root.